# Shell script to email CPU utilization by email

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am a beginner in shell scripting, I am looking for a script to add as cron job that can send email or alert an email ID with the CPU percentage from the top command.

This script is basically to bring into attention the user the peak CPU usage of a server. If there are any scripts that do this or anything better to monitor CPU usage/memory usage please point me to it.

Thanks,
Abi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where your `mail` is in your linux flavor, you can try

```
*/10 * * * * /bin/ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | /bin/sort -k 1 -r | /bin/mail youremail@where.com
```

This will send you, every 10 minutes, the cpu usage sorted from the highest to the lowest.

Comment: I would recommend adding a -n to sort. It sorts the values numerically instead of lexically. (https://ss64.com/bash/sort.html)